# Table within a drop down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Can anyone help me with how to place a table within a drop down list? So instead of clicking on items in a list, I want the users to see a complete and being able to select an item by clicking on a row in the table.

Thanks in advance!

The Code Buccaneer

Comment: I'm wondering if you are trying to solve the same thing I'm stuck on. I want the drop down in an Excel 2010 table to show to columns of information (example: EXA, Definition of EXA; TGF, Definition of TGF; etc) so the user knows which selection to make, but I only want the first column to be stored in the cell from which the list dropped-down. Basically, the drop down list is another "mini" table of more than one column to help make the choice. Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is called an autocomplete. There are several JS scripts and jQuery plugins implementing this UI widget, but there's no native HTML way of doing it - you will need some JS.

Comment: Can you draw a rough mockup of the functionality you are thinking of? I'm having a hard time understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Actually, that is not exactly what I meant. An autocomplete involves the program predicting a word or phrase that the user wants to type in without the user actually typing it in completely. I want to show a complete table in the dropdown without any autocomplete functionality.